# LTM Load Balancer drops connection while App waiting for big SQL query response

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, load-balancing

Newly implemented LTM Load Balancer drops connection while our App is waiting for big SQL query response.

Now I need to find some workaround because apparently extending timeouts on LB is not a way to go.

App runs on Django and MSSQL

Is there any possibility to lets say:

- send query to DB
- get some kind of transaction ID (JWT?)
- close connection
- create GET with some transaction ID to check if there is result of this query? (Not sure how this transaction ID would be stored on DB side though)

Is pagination doing something like this?

I would like to avoid making this like this:

Create API endpoint which runs queries to DB

- Send request to API
- DB process with query and put results in new table
- send query to new table

Comment: Best approach would be to sort the performance of your query. Its sounds like its taking far too long.

Comment: picking up 60,000 records from 2,000,000 takes longer than minute which is set as timeout on LB

Comment: Do you actually need all 60,000 records at the same time? And if you really do, batch them, pull then back 10,000 at a time or so.